# How to find the closest size to but no greater than W x H by aspect ratio?

Tags: algorithms, arithmetic

Giving the size `W x H` and the aspect ratio `X : Y`, how to find the closest size within W x H that matching X : Y? For example:

Input

```
W = 599, H = 599, X = 1, Y = 2
```

Output

```
W = 299, H = 598
```

Input

```
W = 757, H = 611, X = 3, Y = 2
```

Output

```
W = 756, H = 504
```

all of W,H,X,Y are positive integers

Comment: So all of W,H,X,Y are positive integers? Also what is your test for how close X:Y matches a given W:H?

Comment: @coffeemath: presumably yes.  I suspect you need the largest case bounded by $W,H$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An algorithm:

1. reduce $X:Y$ to lowest terms, so for example if given $6:4$ then change this to $3:2$
2. find the smaller of $\frac W X$ and $\frac H Y$ with the reduced $X$ and $Y$ from (1), and round this down to an integer; let's call it $k$
3. use $kX$ and $kY$ with the reduced $X$ and $Y$ from (1)

So with $W = 599, H = 599, X = 1, Y = 2$, you start with $X$ and $Y$ in lowest terms.  Then $k = \lfloor\min(\frac{599}{1},\frac{599}{2})\rfloor=\lfloor\min(599,299.5)\rfloor=299$ and multiplying this by $1:2$ you get $299 \times 598$

while with $W = 757, H = 611, X = 1, Y = 2$, you start with $X$ and $Y$ in lowest terms.  Then $k = \lfloor\min(\frac{757}{3},\frac{611}{2})\rfloor=\lfloor\min(252.33,305.5)\rfloor=252$ and multiplying this by $3:2$ you get $756 \times 504$

Comment: Thanks for the algorithm, I have added mine but in programming language, as this is a math question, I'd accept your answer that is more proper.